# Filling 2 inputs based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to fill 2 fields based on the selection of a dropdown. This is the code I am using now (which works but not work in my case):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateinput(){
var e = document.getElementById("event");
var catSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

document.getElementById("minLvl").value=catSelected;
}
</script>
```

and the relevant HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Event:</td>
        <td>
          <select name="Event" id="event" onChange="updateinput();">
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
            <option value="option4">option4</option>
            <option value="option5">option5</option>
            <option value="option6">option6</option>
            <option value="option7">option7</option>
          </select>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Starting Time:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dateTime"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Level Range:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" id="minLvl"> - <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" id="maxLvl"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Notes:</td>
        <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Create Event:</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Create event!"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know I can use `e.options[e.selectedIndex].text` to get the text and place it in the input, but is there a way I could add attributes to each option so its like `<option value="option1" minLvl="1" maxLvl="10">Option1</option>` and then pull the data from `minLvl` and `maxLvl` and then populate the values into the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateinput(){
var e = document.getElementById("event");
var minLvl = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute("minLvl");
var maxLvl = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute("maxLvl");

document.getElementById("minLvl").value=minLvl;
document.getElementById("maxLvl").value=maxLvl;
}
</script>
```

`<option value="option" minLvl="1" maxLvl="3">option</option>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateinput(){
var e = document.getElementById("event");
var catSelected = this.value;

document.getElementById("minLvl").value=catSelected;
}

<select name="Event" id="event" onChange="updateinput(this);">
```

Comment: Results are turning `undefined`. I don't see where it is grabbing the attribute `minLvl` from the option selected.